# Hive: select * from table fails for tables having more than 5000 rows via HiveServer2

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table sdh in Hive which has 100000 rows.
When I execute the command

`select * from sdh` on CLI, all rows are displayed

But the same command just hangs when I run it via HiveServer2 on beeline

All other tables which have 1000 odd rows work fine via CLI or beeline.

Anyone else face similar issue?

I got error from logs

```
org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing FetchResults
    at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:108)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_FetchResults(TCLIService.java:489)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.FetchResults(TCLIService.java:476)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet.next(HiveQueryResultSet.java:285)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BufferedRows.<init>(BufferedRows.java:42)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.print(BeeLine.java:1541)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:741)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:657)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.dispatch(BeeLine.java:763)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.begin(BeeLine.java:630)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.mainWithInputRedirection(BeeLine.java:363)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.main(BeeLine.java:346)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
```

Error: Error retrieving next row (state=,code=0)

Comment: Ok..got the error from logs

Answer (score 0):

Use the option "--incremental=false" with beeline. Otherwise, it tries to read the entire results into memory at same time, and runs out of memory if the results are too large for available memory.

More discussion on making this option the default is here - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7224

Comment: I think you want true, rather than false. Also from the jira it seems like this option is still quite bugged, but if it works your results should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the option `--incremental=true` and place it before the `-e` option in beeline. For me it worked that way.

Comment: This answer seems a little incomplete - perhaps you should enhance it